# Complete an action AFTER a process loads

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2010

The issue is that we have a lot of very computer illiterate people where I work.  We have 4 applications that have to be ran in order so that these guys can complete their jobs.  They have to run a wireless card, then Cisco VPN, after VPN connects they have to run a transport program, followed by the mobile application that allows them to complete work orders.

My goal is to make this stupid proof (or as proofed as I can) by having an application they can run that runs the programs step by step.  As of now, the program just has 4 buttons, steps 1-4.  Right now it loads with only "Step 1" visible, when they click on it it runs the first program and then shows the next button, and also makes the current button green with text saying the program started, and also makes it not-clickable to keep them from opening a program 30 times (because they will).

All that works great, button by button.  But what I would like to do is to click on Step 1 (button label "Step1") and then it shows text in the button that says "Starting program", when the program is up it then changes the button to a green background with "Program Started" for the text, then shows the next button.

Here is the code for the buttons:

```
    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Rectangle workingArea = Screen.GetWorkingArea(this);
        this.Location = new Point(workingArea.Right - Size.Width, workingArea.Bottom - Size.Height);
        Step2.Visible = false;
        Step3.Visible = false;
        Step4.Visible = false;
    }

    private void Step1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Step1.BackColor = Color.LightGreen;
        Step1.Text = "Verizon Wireless Card";
        string strVzWireless = "C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Verizon Wireless\\VZAccess Manager\\VZAccess Manager.exe";
        Process VzWireless = Process.Start(strVzWireless);
        Step2.Visible = true;
        Step1.Enabled = false;
    }

    private void Step2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Step2.BackColor = Color.LightGreen;
        Step2.Text = "Cisco VPN Client";
        string strCisco = "C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Cisco\\Cisco AnyConnect VPN Client\\vpnui.exe";
        Process Cisco = Process.Start(strCisco);
        Step3.Visible = true;
        Step2.Enabled = false;
    }

    private void Step3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Step3.BackColor = Color.LightGreen;
        Step3.Text = "Client Rf Transport";
        string strRfTransport = "C:\\MWM\\MobileStation\\RfTransport\\RfTransport.exe";
        Process RfTransport = Process.Start(strRfTransport);
        Step4.Visible = true;
        Step3.Enabled = false;
    }

    private void Step4_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Step4.BackColor = Color.LightGreen;
        Step4.Text = "Mobile Station";
        string strMobileStation = "C:\\MWM\\MobileStation\\Station.exe";
        Process MobileStation = Process.Start(strMobileStation);
        Step4.Enabled = false;
    }
```

Any ideas?  I just want button 1 to change colors and text based on the status of the process being running, then show button 2, and so on.

Comment: best opening statement i've seen.

Comment: What Reed Copsey said (+1ed) or `Process.Start().WaitForExit();`

Comment: @Sayse `WaitForExit()` will work, but will block, so you'll get no UI notification (may be okay, but likely bad)

Comment: @ReedCopsey - Ah your right, I overlooked the method name and assumed it was a console app

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Comment: But will WaitForExit() wait on the application to end?  For example, I want to just make sure the verizon access manager is running before moving on to the next step, or even better, wait until it has a network connection established.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

One option would be to launch your process on a background thread, then use [`Process.WaitForInputIdle()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8d7363e2.aspx) to wait until it's launched and in a "ready" state.  You could then launch the second step in the process, etc.

Comment: But doesn't using `Exited` assume that it will?  Sounds to me like it's launching other apps that continue to run.  What about `Process.WaitForInputIdle()`?

Comment: that seems reasonable, never used that before, but seems useful.  one thing to note, it looks like console apps will return from this immediately

Answer (score 2):

`Process.WaitForInputIdle()` is probably what you're looking for -- it'll wait until the process is ready to accept messages, which is a good indicator in general of when the process starts.  (http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2010/03/25/9984720.aspx)

The weakness with trying to do a program like this is, if there's a non-zero amount of work the user needs to do with each application before the next starts up, they could end up just clicking all of the steps in rapid succession, perform no configuration, and wonder why things don't work.  You might want to investigate the programs you're working with to see if they can be automated (via command line or configuration files, perhaps), and take the work off of the user, so that they don't end up hosing themselves a different way.

Comment: Well, part of that will be for the next version, this one just needs to see if the process is running, if it is, let them go to the next step.  Eventually, it'll check to see if the card has a connection, the next step will make sure vpn is actually connected, etc etc, but for now I just need to make sure the program is actually running.